# Apache2: Unable to resolve the request "site". yii framework

Tags: php, apache, yii

I have set virtual host for my project *(Yii based applcation)*, in apach2/site-enabled/default.conf file. In DocumentRoot i have set correct path and has done all the correct step. I have checked all the log files including apache2 and yii application runtime but there is nothing. when i enter url in the browser it gives,
***Unable to resolve the request "site"***
 I created a test application to test the apache server, it works on the test application but not working on my project.

Could any body help me, why it is happening ?

Comment: what is your .htaccess file content?

Comment: put a echo and exit in yii root index.php file and check if it works ?

Comment: These are content of .htaccess file  @AndreyMischenko

RewriteEngine on

# prevent httpd from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
RedirectMatch 403 /\..*$
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

Comment: @Hemc I have tried echo in index.php but it is not working.

Comment: Then problem is not with Yii, Yii application run in index.php file, if server is not able to run this , ot will not be able to run yii application

Comment: check permission to your project root folder

Answer (score 0):

Which url are you using?

Generally, the default controller of a Yii application is `SiteController` so that the index page is linked to that controller.

Ensure that you have a folder *site* in `protected/views`, or change the default controller to `protected/config/main.php` to meet your needs.